# Is it ok to use Next JS 12's api routes to fetch protected images into Next Image component?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image, nextjs-dynamic-routing

The images on the backend are behind a Basic Authentication. I've created a Next JS API route to set Basic Auth Request headers to the request and set that route as the URL to the Next Image component, since the Next Image component doesn't allow us to set custom Request HTTP Headers.

```js
// pages/api/image/index.ts

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const id = req.query.id;
  const response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `https://protected-images.com/images/${id}`,
    responseType: "stream",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${decodeURIComponent(token)}`,
    },
  });
  response.data.pipe(res);
}
```

```js
        <Image
          src={`/api/image/${id-of-protected-image}`}
          alt={title || ""}
          layout={"fill"}
          objectFit={objectFit}
          objectPosition={objectPosition}
          className={className || ""}
        />
```

Will this cause high usage of server-less functions on Vercel as all the images will be served via my custom API route ? I want to know if this is an OK solution to render protected images on Next JS 12 or is there any alternative ?